# How to type key combinations instead of pressing them?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I prefer to have my index fingers resting on <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>J</kbd> all the time when I type. It causes me much distress whenever I have to run to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key or the <kbd>End</kbd> key or the <kbd>Home</kbd> key or the <kbd>arrow keys</kbd>! It is worse when you have to press a combination - something like: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Is there a way where instead of pressing the key combinations, I can activate some mode at the OS level (i.e. - not application specific and works everywhere) where I type in the key combination in words. For example I would type in something like `control shift s` to mean the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, without actually pressing the combination.

That is, I am willing to press more keys if needed, but I would not prefer to move my hands from my resting place!

Is there a solution for a Linux based OS, say Ubuntu?

**EDIT:** I would like this to work across applications. For example it should work on my browser, on my editor etc. It should work on any future application that I may ever install.

That is I need an interface/filter/translator between my keyboard and the OS, that will translate what I type into appropriate commands or key combinations.

For example say I am in Libre Office where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> is used for Print command.

Then I would want to do something like this: Type `control p` instead of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>P</kbd> together. And that should get translated to the correct key combination and fed into Libre Office.

In particular it shouldn't matter what application I am using. I want to create verbose aliases for some difficult to reach keys and when I just type out those aliases, the machine should behave as if I had pressed the key combination instead.

This is how I imagine it to work (I am adding all these details to explain more clearly what I am looking for):

1. Say I want to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Press a special key combination say <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and that would activate this "translation" mode.
3. Type `control shift r`. While typing I may use backspace. For example the key strokes may be: `com(backspace)ntri(backspace)ol S(backspace)shift,(backspace) r`. Then that should just mean `control shift r` because if I were to type that out on an editor, it would be that.
4. Press a special key combination say <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>. That would then "translate" everything that was typed between the first special key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and the last special key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and send the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to the machine.

Comment: The answer you got was for terminal (bash specifically) because you didn't specify.  If your question is about the Graphical Interface, you should state that.

Comment: Does this need to be in X or plain old terminal? The ways od doing this would be different.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek has killed my answer where I was proposing using speech recognition for typing in bash and applications. If you like that idea you will need to research it - a comment is too short to contain all the links I listed for you.

Comment: @Inspired_Blue have you checked the "Accessibility" options for Unity/KDE/Gnome whatever you're using?

Comment: @MichaelD. I guess I have and I didn't find what I was looking for. I don't think sticky key solves my problems entirely. I want my keys to be remapped as well. And there should be a convenient way to toggle between the usual keyboard and remapped keyboard with sticky mode. Do you know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: The referred to deleted answer is nothing more than grabbing a few links from a Google search for "speech recognition ubuntu" If you want to know more that's the entirely of the deleted answer

Comment: Are you saying Alt and Ctrl are not on the same row on your keyboard?

Comment: @random: "Chosen links", please.

Comment: Yes, the chosen links are the links found on the first page of a Google search result

Answer (score 0):

You can create aliases in your

```
~/.bashrc
```

ie.

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```

or to open a picture with gimp

```
alias g='gimp $@'

# open myimage.jpg
g myimage.jpg
```

Comment: hmm. Can an alias have a space? Is there something that will generate a key combination that would work in conjunction with this?

Comment: Yes this is very useful. But I am looking for a solution that would work beyond the terminal or command line.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are trying to do here, but it sounds like the `vi` editor might do what you want. It has 3 modes:

1. An "Insert mode" for simply typing your document
2. Then there is a "Command mode" where all letters have a meta meaning and are used to send commands to the program.
3. The final mode is a so called "Last line" mode which is a subset of the "Command" mode and lets you search for text, save the file, etc.

http://alvinalexander.com/linux/vim-vi-mode-editor-command-insert-mode

`vi` normally uses a single key `esc` to toggle between modes, but this can probably be remapped to another key.

In general, you will probably need to use *some special key* for toggling commands, otherwise there is no way for the computer to know if you are typing words or telling it to *do* something.

Comment: Well I would like this to work across applications and not just on vi. It should work even on my browser. It should work on any future application that I may ever install. The idea is that it is possible to remap keys, or use sticky keys to type key combinations one key at a time. So I need an interface/ filter between my keyboard and the OS, that will translate what I type into appropriate commands. I want this dictionary to be something as simple as a text file.